# How do you manage function scope and synchronization in Python 3

Tags: python

This a 2-question rolled into 1 - I get the following output from the script next

```
Checker: start of thread
Checker: ( 0 ) Hello, world
Checker: ( 1 ) Hello, world
Checker: ( 2 ) How do you do
Checker: ( 3 ) How do you do
Checker: start of thread
Checker: ( 4 ) Bye for now
Checker: exiting thread
Checker: ( 0 ) Bye for now
Checker: exiting thread
```

The script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python                                                                                                                           

import time
import threading

class CheckTscope:

def __init__ (self):
    self.name = 'checker'
    self.msg = None

def checker (self, msg="Hey stranger"):
    count = 0
    self.setMessage(msg)
    print ("Checker: start of thread")
    while True:
        time.sleep (0.04)
        print ("Checker: (", count, ")", self.getMessage())
        if self.carry_on:
            count += 1
            continue
        break
    print ("Checker: exiting thread")

def getMessage (self):
    return self.msg

def setMessage (self, text):
    self.msg = text

def construct (self, initxt):
    self.setMessage (initxt)
    self.carry_on = True
    reporter = threading.Thread(target=self.checker, args=(initxt,))
    reporter.start()

def destruct (self):
    self.carry_on = False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ct = CheckTscope()
    ct.construct("Hello, world")
    time.sleep(0.125)
    ct.setMessage("How do you do")
    time.sleep(0.06)
    ct.destruct()
    time.sleep(0.02)
    ct.checker ("Bye for now")
```

The questions:

1. How can I make the function checker() accessible only to other functions in this class (limit the scope)?
2. How do I synchronize for multiple threads ("4 - Bye for now" is an error, counter should be reset when message is set to new value).

Essentially, I am looking for a replacement of "synchronized private void" from another language. Thank you for your help.

Comment: you can use **underscores** to make a variable or method private.at least one for `variables` (_somevar) and at least two for `methods` (__someMethod).see here => https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables

Comment: Python doesn't really have private attributes or methods. You can use a _single_ leading underscore to mark an attribute or method private, but that's merely a convention, Python doesn't enforce any conditions on such objects. The slogan is "We're all consenting adults here".

Comment: @shotgunner I don't know where you learned that, but it's not correct. Please see [What is the meaning of a single- and a double-underscore before an object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name)

Comment: @PM2Ring oops, you're right.I've got mistake

Comment: There are various tools to assist in synchronization available in the `threading` module. You could probably use a simple `Lock` or `Event` for this task. Also note that in recent versions of Python there are more modern alternatives to the threading module. Please see [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html).

Comment: Please don't roll two questions into one. How will you decide which answer to accept if one person answers question 1, and another person answers question 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - you dont. Scope of methods and variables is most of the time handled by programming conventions. In this case you would add a underline in the beggining of the checker to identify it as a private method that should only be called by the other methods inside the class.
2 - to synchronize multiple threads you need to work with the the threads using threading specific commands, trying to use the "carry_on" like you did will make you end in some weird alleys.
Ps: if I recall there is the @Async and @Sync annotations, you could look further into it.

Comment: Thank you. "You cannot do this" is a perfectly valid answer :)

Comment: Python is very permissive, so we depend heavily in good pratices and conventios, pep, etc

Comment: Messing around with my code and reading up stuff here - I figured that changing the method name from checker to __checker solves 1 problem (makes it private) - with the error: "AttributeError: 'CheckTscope' object has no attribute '__checker'".